# Is using a generic better here, or is the interface enough?

Tags: c#, interface, generics

Are there any advantages to using the first, generic-based method instead of the second method which simply utilizes an interface?

```
class MyClass
{
    public static void Method<T>(T t) where T:IBar
    {            
    }

    public static void Method(IBar bar)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case having a interface type as constraint is not useful.

But sometimes it is, e.g. :

```
interface IHasId
{
   public int Id { get; }
}

public static IList<int> GetIds<T>(IList<T> items) where T:IHasId
{            
    return items.Select(item => item.Id).ToList();
}
```

in this (very silly) case you have the advantage that you can pass a `IList<IHasIdImplementation>` while in non-generic case you would have to pass `IList<IHasId>`.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I don't see any advantage of using generics in this particular case.

Comment: I saw some examples in which they used generic type by interface constraint and i just wanted to understand why they prefered generic type constraint instead of using interface.

Comment: @Freshblood, maybe you could refer to those examples? It's kind of difficult for us knowing what you saw. We see what you show, and what you show doesn't require any generics IMHO.

Comment: Wrong thing is constraint should not be by a type ?

Comment: @Freshblood, erh, pardon me? I am not sure I understand your previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are two scenarios where I've found I need to use generics in a method definition.

The first is when the return value needs to be specified by the generic type value.  So when it's like:

```
public T Method1<T>(object someobject) where T:IBar;
```

The second scenario is when you need to use the type parameter (not just an interface) inside the method.

An example of both requirements is a GetModelByKey() method in a ViewModelFactory class.  This class caches ViewModels by ViewModelType and KeyType, and the resulting method looks like:

```
public ViewModelType GetViewModelByKey<ViewModelType, KeyType>(KeyType key) 
        where ViewModelType : ViewModelBase, new()
    {
        IDictionary dictionary;
        var type = typeof(ViewModelType);
        if (!keyedViewModelDictionaries.TryGetValue(type, out dictionary))
        {
            dictionary = new Dictionary<KeyType, ViewModelType>();
            keyedViewModelDictionaries.Add(type, dictionary);
        }
        var viewModels = (Dictionary<KeyType, ViewModelType>)dictionary;
        ViewModelType vm;
        if (!viewModels.TryGetValue(key, out vm))
        {
            vm = new ViewModelType();
            vm.Initialize(this);
            viewModels.Add(key, vm);
        }
        return vm;
    }
```